# Complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I'm not sure how to solve this integral:

$$\int_\gamma {e^{|z|^2}}Re (z)$$ with $\gamma$ being the segment with vertices $0$ and $1+i$.

I started this by saying that $f(z)= {e^{|z|²}}Re (z) = xe^{x²}e^{y²} $

$\gamma (t) = t \; , \;t \; \epsilon \; [0,1] $

But what do I do know? Should I calculate $f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$?

If so, the integral would become:

$\int_0^1 te^{t²}e^{t²}dt$

I don't feel like this is right. What am I doing wrong?

PS: Is there a way to make the latex font bigger? The exponents are quite hard to see, I think.

Comment: Your integrand is not holomorphic, so you need to specify precisely what the integration contour is to get a value.

Comment: Why do you write $\;\gamma=\gamma_1+\gamma_2\;$ ? Aren't you **given** that the integration path is the (straight) segment from $\;0\;$ to $\;1+i\;$ ? You don't get to choose the path: you're given the path.

Comment: @DonAntonio, you're right. How would I define that path though? $\gamma (t) = t$?

Comment: It's just the straight line $\;y=x\;$ in the complex plane ! You can parametrize (two variables) as $$x:=t\in[0,1]\;,\;\;y=x=t$$

Comment: You can parameterize the line by $\gamma(t) = (1+i)t$, which is a straight line with $\gamma(0) = 0$ and $\gamma(1) = 1+i$.  Then $f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) = (1+i)te^{2t^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we've the line $\;\gamma:\;\;y=x\;,\;\;0\le x\le 1\;\implies\;dz=d(x+iy)=(1+i)dx$ , we get

$$\int\limits_\gamma e^{|z|^2}\text{Re}\,(z)\,dz=(1+i)\int\limits_0^1xe^{2x^2}dx=\frac14(1+i)\int\limits_0^1(4x\,dx)e^{2x^2}=$$

$$=\left.\frac14(1+i)e^{2x^2}\right|_0^1=\frac14\left(e^2-1\right)(1+i)$$

And that is the final answer.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? I ask because I got that result a couple times and the solutions (in the book) give another answer. That's the reason why I created this question.

Comment: I'm only sure I am not sure...I can't see though how this elementary thing can be wrong, but it undoubtedly can. Now, *what* solutions "give another answer"? Is that from some book orsomething like that?

Comment: It's from a book, and it gives this solution: $(e²-1)(1+i)/4$

Comment: You're missing $dz = (1+i)dx$.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it may be that I'm wrong and the book's right since I'm observing now I solved that above *just* as a real integral yet we're not **really** on the real plane but on the complex one, and thus we should have taken that into account!

Comment: Exactly, Antonio! I completely forgot the complex thing; I went on the real one only.+1

Comment: @Crake, I've edited my answer in view of Antonio's precise comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio, there's a mistake. $dz = (1+i)dx$ and not $(1+y)dx$, as it says in your answer, correct?

Comment: Of course, @Crake . Thanks